# Permission denied, please try again - when trying to ssh to a machine

Tags: ssh

On the server machine we could see the below logs entries from /var/log/auth.log

sshd[xxx]: Failed password for root from x.x.x.x port xxxx ssh2

On Client machine we could see the below entry when we try ssh -vvv root@x.x.x.x

```
root@x.x.x.x's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 59 padlen 5 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 148 bytes for a total of 1985
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

**Solution** that worked for me

On the server machine from /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

Uncomment

**permitRootLogin yes**

**PasswordAuthentication yes**

Comment: You should separate question and answer.

Comment: Also,  you probably don't need to uncomment `PasswordAuthentication yes`  And it's perhaps better if  it's `PasswordAuthentication no`  Clearly it's the `permitRootLogin yes` that you needed, so your solution was that rather than anything about PasswordAuthentication.

Comment: So post an answer yourself with the solution, then remove the solution from the question.